# Cannot yum install vdo kmod-kvdo

Tags: centos7, virtual-machines, installation, yum, openvz

I am trying to install kmod-kvdo and vdo but I get these errors.

```
yum install vdo
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, openvz, priorities
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     | 4.5 kB     00:00
 * base: mirror.domainhizmetleri.com
 * epel: hkg.mirror.rackspace.com
 * extras: centos.vargonen.com
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * openvz-os: ftp.nluug.nl
 * openvz-updates: ftp.nluug.nl
 * updates: mirror.isimtescil.com.tr
base                                                     | 3.6 kB     00:00
epel                                                     | 4.7 kB     00:00
extras                                                   | 2.9 kB     00:00
nux-dextop                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00
openvz-os                                                | 3.9 kB     00:00
openvz-updates                                           | 3.0 kB     00:00
updates                                                  | 2.9 kB     00:00
(1/3): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                         | 3.0 MB   00:10
(2/3): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                              | 1.0 MB   00:23
(3/3): epel/x86_64/primary_db                              | 6.8 MB   00:45
153 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vdo.x86_64 0:6.1.3.4-4.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kmod-kvdo >= 6.1 for package: vdo-6.1.3.4-4.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kmod-kvdo.x86_64 0:6.1.3.7-5.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0xeeeae71b for package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(dm_register_target) = 0x979ddcc5 for package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x412d503d for package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: kernel(dm_get_device) = 0xa425b4a9 for package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x412d503d
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0xe484e3b5
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1062.4.2.vz7.116.7.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x74e56bb4
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x3dd977c7
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 (base)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x821aceef
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x821aceef
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x821aceef
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x821aceef
           Available: vzkernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_put_device) = 0x0c584695
Error: Package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0xeeeae71b
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0x35ba4186
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1062.4.2.vz7.116.7.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0x50a1f28d
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0x0d9db791
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 (base)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0xed37721f
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0xed37721f
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0xed37721f
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0xed37721f
           Available: vzkernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_unregister_target) = 0x74d53bbe
Error: Package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: kernel(dm_register_target) = 0x979ddcc5
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xd3f9ecc7
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1062.4.2.vz7.116.7.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xc644c4ca
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xaf21d309
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 (base)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xb38b6b62
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xb38b6b62
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xb38b6b62
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0xb38b6b62
           Available: vzkernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_register_target) = 0x5cfd362a
Error: Package: kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: kernel(dm_get_device) = 0xa425b4a9
           Installed: kernel-3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0x602cd186
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1062.4.2.vz7.116.7.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0x4b672758
           Installed: vzkernel-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (@openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0x105d3ca0
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 (base)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0x7daf0344
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0x7daf0344
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.10.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0x7daf0344
           Available: kernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 (updates)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0x7daf0344
           Available: vzkernel-debug-3.10.0-1127.8.2.vz7.151.14.x86_64 (openvz-os)
               kernel(dm_get_device) = 0xf754ea18
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Try this: yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=base install vdo kmod-kvdo

Comment: @Overmind I did that. and I got the same error

Comment: Then you could try to install/update kernel(dm_put_device) linux packages and then get the official rpm (like this one: https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/kmod-kvdo-6.1.3.7-5.el7.x86_64.rpm.html )

Comment: @Overmind what is dm_put_device anyway. why it does not show the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VDO and in particular its kernel module are built specifically for the associated RHEL/CentOS kernels. Your server, however, has OpenVZ, which uses a custom kernel. At this time using VDO with a custom kernel is not supported.

In order to install this, you would need to obtain the source RPM for kmod-kvdo and then rebuild the RPM against the particular vzkernel you want it to work with. And probably you'd need to customize it too, as it would expect a `kernel` rather than a `vzkernel`. You would need to repeat this process for every kernel update.

Comment: Thanks. Do I need vdo for Virtualization? When I create a new VM i get error: unknow input device type virtio1.0-input. is this related to vdo?

Comment: @MehdiAzizi That is completely irrelevant to VDO.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what should I do? or I should create a new question for that?

Comment: You should ask a new question about that.

Comment: I uninstalled vdo and kmod-kvdo and so far I have no problem. I thought it was necessary for KVM. Is this vdo needed for  OpenVz or it's not. I don't know How it has been installed on my system.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a bug in yum preventing from installation and moreover it may not work due to compatibility issues. Looking for workaround.